# Create Dynamic Control Flow chart using jQuery with PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I want to implement Flow Chart feature, where user needs to be able to create flow chart using the tool, and user needs to able save the flow chart for further use.

I am using below plugin: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/chart-graph/Simple-SVG-Flow-Chart-Plugin-with-jQuery-flowSVG.html

**But it has following issues:**

1. Does not support drag and drop elements to the flow chart for now -
   I am using option in the DD to add new element.
2. Can't Select, Delete or Edit the element.

I need flow chart for live users so that user can create and attach elements to the live processes or users. ( process/user is like a DB record with the ID)

By using above plugin I can create element and attach but because of the above issues it got fail.

- if you have similar plugin with drag and drop and selectable features elements please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can user paper.js. It has a lot of features.

[edit] Is not a library that creates a flow chart right out of the box, but with ease you can create some great drawings with it.

Comment: paper.js is not going to help me, I need to attached flow chart elements to live process, users and decision. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: U'r welcome. Check this out to see if it fits to your needs. http://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html

Comment: Sure, I am going to check this in to more detail.. it seems it has drag and drop with json output, thanks for you great help.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [gojs](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/flowchart.html). GoJS is a JavaScript and TypeScript library for building interactive diagrams and graphs.